# ZPanelcp , Domains activation not work

Tags: apache2

-Hello everyone , I just rent an a dedicated server (ubuntu 12.4) and i install apache + php, mySQL etc ...but using SSH to creat domains (virtual hosts) it is a litle bit laborer so I decided to install some GUI admin panel and also  decided for ZPanelcp last version so everything installed fine without errors and I set first time two domains  something like :

new.domain.com

new.otherdomain.com

these domains has been activated successfully without set zpanel DNS for those domains but next day I notice when I try to  create again other domains in my ZPanel show as "live" but in my webbrowser can not see so  in reality they were not activated , ok first time I Run Daemon again and restart BIND also restart apache I try a few changes in my server conf files but nothing I reboot my server also nothing my server use one static ip.

Here are my Zpanel, apache2  conf files.

Apache2 files:

*folder files:*

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
# Here is last lines of this files  related to my problem
# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see the comments above for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/


ServerName cp.zpanel.com
Include /etc/zpanel/configs/apache/httpd.conf
```

**/etc/apache2/ports.conf**

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride All
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride All
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/zpanel/configs/apache/httpd.conf**

```
# ZPanel Apache Include file for CentOS Linux
# Written by Bobby Allen, 15/05/2011

# Set the Zpanel Alias (used for development, sable will eventually use a VHOST)
Alias /zpanel /etc/zpanel/panel

# Setup the directory settings and PHP security flags for the Zpanel application directory.
<Directory /etc/zpanel/panel>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
                php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
                php_flag track_vars On
                php_flag register_globals Off
                php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/zpanel/temp
        </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it/that we don't want people looking in!
<Directory /etc/zpanel/panel/cnf>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>

# Set server tokens (security??)
ServerTokens Maj

# Now we include the generic VHOST configuration file that holds all the ZPanel user hosted vhost data
Include /etc/zpanel/configs/apache/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**/etc/zpanel/configs/apache/httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
################################################################
# Apache VHOST configuration file
# Automatically generated by ZPanel 10.0.1
# Generated on: 09:15 13th Dec 2012 CET
################################################################

NameVirtualHost *:80

# Configuration for ZPanel control panel.
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin zadmin@localhost
DocumentRoot "/etc/zpanel/panel/"
ServerName cp.zpanel.com
ServerAlias *.cp.zpanel.com
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
<Directory "/etc/zpanel/panel/">
Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

# Custom settings are loaded below this line (if any exist)

</VirtualHost>

################################################################
# ZPanel generated VHOST configurations below.....
################################################################


# DOMAIN: new.domain.com
<virtualhost *:80>
ServerName new.domain.com
ServerAlias new.domain.com www.new.domain.com
ServerAdmin zadmin@localhost
DocumentRoot "/var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/new_domain_com"
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/new_domain_com:/var/zpanel/temp/"
php_admin_value suhosin.executor.func.blacklist "passthru, show_source, shell_exec, system, pcntl_exec, popen, pclose, proc_open, proc_nice, proc_terminate, proc_get_status, proc_close, leak, apache_child_$
ErrorLog "/var/zpanel/logs/domains/zadmin/new.domain.com-error.log"
CustomLog "/var/zpanel/logs/domains/zadmin/new.domain.com-access.log" combined
CustomLog "/var/zpanel/logs/domains/zadmin/new.domain.com-bandwidth.log" common
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3 .php
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/_cgi-bin/"
<location /cgi-bin>
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
Options ExecCGI -Indexes
</location>
ErrorDocument 403 /_errorpages/403.html
ErrorDocument 500 /_errorpages/500.html
ErrorDocument 404 /_errorpages/404.html
ErrorDocument 510 /_errorpages/510.html
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.asp index.aspx index.jsp index.jspa index.shtml index.shtm
# Custom Global Settings (if any exist)

# Custom VH settings (if any exist)

</virtualhost>
# END DOMAIN: new.domain.com
################################################################
##ETC other domains##
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
### Hetzner Online AG installimage
# nameserver config
# IPv4
127.0.0.1 localhost
6.8.81.52  Ubuntu-1210-quantal-64-minimal
#
# IPv6
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Comment: I would suggest asking this on either [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/), or _possibly_ [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) (Though webmasters doesn't seem to handle server config as much as design/seo type issues. ^^)

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of httpd-vhosts.conf file. Maybe you don't have write permission.